# SQL Server get the highest date from all datetime columns of all tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a bunch of tables where some have datetime columns and some don't. For all the tables that contain datetime columns, I want to find the maximum value and output that. What I've done so far is this:

```
DECLARE @AllTables TABLE (TableNumber INT, TableName NVARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @AllColumns TABLE (ColumnNumber INT, ColumnName NVARCHAR(255), TableName NVARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @OrderedColumns TABLE (EntryNumber INT, ColumnName NVARCHAR(255), TableName NVARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @J INT = 1

DECLARE @TableCount INT
DECLARE @ColumnCount INT

DECLARE @CurrentTableName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @CurrentColumnName NVARCHAR(255)

DECLARE @HighestDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TotalHighestDate DATETIME = '1970-01-01'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

--List all relevant tables
INSERT INTO @AllTables
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS Row, TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'XYZ%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

SET @TableCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @AllTables)

--Loop through all the tables and get the column names for datetime columns
WHILE @I <= @TableCount
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentTableName = (SELECT TableName FROM @AllTables WHERE TableNumber = @I)
    INSERT INTO @AllColumns
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS Row, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE 'datetime%' AND TABLE_NAME = @CurrentTableName
    SET @I = @I + 1
END

--Order the columns so they can be looped through
INSERT INTO @OrderedColumns
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TableName,ColumnName) AS Row, ColumnName, TableName FROM @AllColumns

SET @ColumnCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @OrderedColumns)

--Get the highest date for each column and update the total highest date if the date we found is higher than the current record holder
WHILE @J <= @ColumnCount
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentColumnName = (SELECT ColumnName FROM @OrderedColumns WHERE EntryNumber = @J)
    SET @CurrentTableName = (SELECT TableName FROM @OrderedColumns WHERE EntryNumber = @J)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @HighestDateOUTPUT = MAX(' + @CurrentColumnName + ') FROM [dbo].[' + @CurrentTableName +']'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,N'@HighestDateOUTPUT DATETIME OUTPUT',@HighestDateOUTPUT = @HighestDate OUTPUT

    --Ignore any results that are in the future, that data is incorrect and should be fixed at the source, not here
    IF (@HighestDate > @TotalHighestDate AND @TotalHighestDate < @CurrentDate AND @HighestDate < @CurrentDate)
    BEGIN
        SET @TotalHighestDate = @HighestDate
    END
    SET @J = @J + 1
END

PRINT @TotalHighestDate
```

This runs fine and correctly outputs the highest date from all columns. The problem is that when I run this as a stored procedure with the procedure being

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyHighestDateProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- ...
    -- The above code block here
    -- ...
END
```

It fails with the error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

About 1 in 4 tries it runs correctly though, which is the strange part. My colleague said that "using dynamic SQL in stored procedures is a nightmare, you are playing with fire, SQL caches the execution plans which can be a problem with these things" so if my approach can be improved by avoiding dynamic SQL then I'm all ears.

EDIT: to clarify, I want to find the single highest date from all the different datetime columns, not the highest date for each column, the result should be one single datetime output.

Comment: your code for me is okay,you can say me way of run sp?you can print @SQL to find problem ?why do you use hard code schema and TABLE_NAME?maybe your tablename or column_name has problem?you has problem when you excuted or created sp ?

Comment: I can run the SP with EXEC [dbo].[stored procedure here] or I can right-click it from SSMS and select Execute, both fails. The SQL doesn't seem to be the issue since it's the exact same code. Run as EXEC sp = fails with syntax error. Right-click the sp > modify > copy the query only and run it as a stand-alone query = works.

Comment: Can you send snapshot your error? Do you print @sp?when you run sp on other databases .you get error?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with snapshot. The stored procedure error is written in the text body here. I've isolated that the issue is related to the dynamically generated SQL statement at ... SET SQL = 'SELECT HighestDateOUTPUT ... EXECUTE sp_executesql ... but I don't understand why when I run the query as it is, it works. But, when I run the stored procedure that runs the exact same query, it fails with syntax error on that bit. Colleague said it was probably because the execution plan is cached so if possible, I'd like to avoid using dynamic SQL altogether but I don't know how.

Comment: changed your stored procedure to include this line `PRINT @SQL` before `sp_executesql`. Test your procedure again. When encounter error, check the `@SQL` that cause the error

Comment: Most probably the error you see is due to the table column name contains space or special character and your dynamic query does not handle it. Change your query to `SET @SQL = 'SELECT @HighestDateOUTPUT = MAX(' + quotename(@CurrentColumnName) + ') FROM [dbo].[' + @CurrentTableName +']'`. You handled the table name but not the column name

Comment: omg that was it, I wasn't even aware of that since all our previous databases has been pretty strict in not allowing spaces but recent integration with other software needed to allow that, I had forgotten about that. If you want to post the QuoteName() answer I'll accept it as the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most probably due to the column name contains space or special character. You can use `quotename()` on the column name to handle such case

Change the dynamic query to

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @HighestDateOUTPUT = MAX(' + quotename(@CurrentColumnName) + ') FROM [dbo].[' + @CurrentTableName +']'.
```

If you are interested, your query can be simplify to

```
-- temp table to store the highest date for each table / column
create table #temp 
(
    table_name sysname,
    column_name sysname,
    highest_date datetime
);

select  @SQL    = string_agg('INSERT INTO #temp (table_name, column_name, highest_date) '
                       + 'SELECT ''' + c.TABLE_NAME + ''' , ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''', '
                       + 'MAX(' + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ') '
                       + 'FROM ' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME), ';' + char(13))
from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where   c.TABLE_NAME    like    'XYZ%'
and     c.DATA_TYPE     like    'datetime%'

exec    (@SQL)

select  max(highest_date)
from    #temp
where   highest_date    < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```